# FastReport (RAD Studio XE7 C++ Builder) - How do you create a sum formula?

Tags: c++builder, fastreport

I am using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7, C++ Builder with FastReport 5. I create a very simple FastReport that adds up some values in a table and prints out a total. I cannot get the syntax for the sum formula correct, and as a result it keeps throwing an access violation error.

To reproduce this problem in RAD Studio XE7:

1. Open RAD Studio XE7 and go to File -> New -> VCL Forms Application - C++Builder
2. Drag a TClientDataSet component named ClientDataSet1 onto the form. Drag a TfrxReport component named frxReport1 onto the form. Drag a TfrxDBDataset named frxDBDataset1 onto the form.
3. Drag a TButton named Button1 onto the form, and double-click it to create an OnClick event handler.
4. Add the following lines to the Button1Click event handler:

   ```
   // Create a simple dataset.

   ClientDataSet1->FieldDefs->Clear();
   ClientDataSet1->FieldDefs->Add("ID", ftInteger, 0, false);
   ClientDataSet1->FieldDefs->Add("Status", ftString, 10, false);
   ClientDataSet1->FieldDefs->Add("Created", ftDate, 0, false);
   ClientDataSet1->FieldDefs->Add("Volume", ftInteger, 0, false);

   try
   {
     ClientDataSet1->CreateDataSet();
   }
   catch(Exception& e)
   {
     ShowMessage("ERROR: '" + e.Message + "'");
     return;
   }

   ClientDataSet1->Open();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
     ClientDataSet1->Append();
     ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("ID")->AsInteger = i;
     ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("Status")->AsString = "Code" + String(i);
     ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("Created")->AsDateTime = Now();
     ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("Volume")->AsInteger = Random(1000);

     try
     {
       ClientDataSet1->Post();
     }
     catch(Exception& e)
     {
       ShowMessage("ERROR: '" + e.Message + "'");
       ClientDataSet1->Close();
       return;
     }
   }

   // Dataset created successfully, now create Fast Report that outputs that dataset

   frxReport1->Clear();
   frxDBDataset1->DataSet = (TDataSet*)ClientDataSet1;

   frxReport1->DataSets->Add(frxDBDataset1);

   TfrxDataPage* DataPage = new TfrxDataPage(frxReport1);
   DataPage->CreateUniqueName();

   TfrxReportPage* Page = new TfrxReportPage(frxReport1);
   Page->CreateUniqueName();

   // set sizes of fields, paper and orientation to defaults
   Page->SetDefaults();
   Page->Orientation = poPortrait;

   TfrxReportTitle* HeaderBand = new TfrxReportTitle(Page);
   HeaderBand->CreateUniqueName();
   HeaderBand->Top = 0;
   HeaderBand->Height = 20;

   TfrxMemoView* Memo = new TfrxMemoView(HeaderBand);
   Memo->CreateUniqueName();
   Memo->Text = "Generic Report";
   Memo->SetBounds(0, 0, 200, 20);

   TfrxHeader* ColumnHeaderBand;
   ColumnHeaderBand = new TfrxHeader(Page);
   ColumnHeaderBand->CreateUniqueName();
   ColumnHeaderBand->Top = HeaderBand->Top + HeaderBand->Height;
   ColumnHeaderBand->Height = 20;

   TfrxMasterData* DataBand = new TfrxMasterData(Page);
   DataBand->Name = "DataBand";
   DataBand->DataSet = frxDBDataset1;
   DataBand->Top = ColumnHeaderBand->Top + ColumnHeaderBand->Height;
   DataBand->Height = 20;

   TfrxMemoView* mField;
   for (int i = 0; i < DataBand->DataSet->FieldsCount(); ++i)
   {
     const String fieldname = ClientDataSet1->Fields->Fields[i]->FieldName;

     mField = new TfrxMemoView(ColumnHeaderBand);
     mField->CreateUniqueName();
     mField->SetBounds(i * 100, 0, 100, 20);
     mField->Text = fieldname;
     mField->HAlign = haCenter;

     // Now do the actual data
     mField = new TfrxMemoView(DataBand);
     mField->CreateUniqueName();
     mField->DataSet = DataBand->DataSet;
     mField->DataField = fieldname;
     mField->SetBounds(i * 100, 0, 100, 20);
     mField->HAlign = haRight;
   }

   // Now do footer band. This will hold the total
   TfrxBand* FooterBand = new TfrxFooter(Page);
   FooterBand->CreateUniqueName();
   FooterBand->Top = DataBand->Top + DataBand->Height;
   FooterBand->Height = HeaderBand->Height;

   TfrxMemoView* totals = new TfrxMemoView(FooterBand);
   totals->Top = 0;
   totals->Left = 0;
   totals->Height = 20;
   totals->Align = baWidth;

   bool is_error = false;
   try
   {
     // ALL OF THESE LINES CAUSE THE ACCESS VIOLATION

     // Create a summation function that displays the volume total
     totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<ClientDataSet1.Volume>, MyDataBand, 1)]";
     //totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<ClientDataSet1.'volume'>,MyDataBand,1)]";
     //totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<ClientDataSet1.\"volume\">,MyDataBand,1)]";
     //totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<ClientDataSet1.""volume"">,MyDataBand,1)]";
     //totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<ClientDataSet1.''volume''>,MyDataBand,1)]";
     //totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<ClientDataSet1.\'volume\'>,MyDataBand,1)]";
   }
   catch(Exception& e)
   {
     ShowMessage("ERROR: '" + e.Message + "'");
     is_error = true;
   }

   if (!is_error)
   {
     frxReport1->ShowReport(true);
   }

   ClientDataSet1->Close();

   ShowMessage("Program complete!");
   ```
5. Compile and run the program. The code in the try block will throw an access violation. Why is this happening? What is the correct syntax to create the sum formula?

**UPDATE:**

I modified the code by explicitly setting a name for frxDBDataset1:

```
    frxReport1->Clear();
    frxDBDataset1->DataSet = (TDataSet*)ClientDataSet1;
    frxDBDataset1->Name = "frxDBDataset1"; // line added
    frxReport1->DataSets->Add(frxDBDataset1);
```

I also changed the formula line to the following:

```
    totals->Text = "Totals: [Sum(<frxDBDataset1.\"Volume\">, DataBand, 1)]";
```

I am still getting the access violation, though.

Comment: Two things: 1) The text for the Totals mentions 'MyDataBand' but your data band is actually called 'DataBand'. 2) It doesn't show in your code what's the name for the dataset. That's a property of the frxDBDataset1. It doesn't have to be necessarily the same name as the actual dataset. - The syntax, at least the one I have and works, is something like this: [SUM(<frxDataSetName."FieldName">,BandName,1)]

Comment: After making those modifications, I am still getting the Access Violation error. See update above.

Comment: What version of FR are you running? I was able to run the program with a few modifications (all of them are what we discussed earlier) without any issues.

I'm running XE5 with FR 4.15.5.

Comment: I am using FastReport version 5.1.5. It is the version that comes preinstalled with Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project --> Options --> Packages --> Runtime Packages. Set "Link with Runtime Packages" to False.

The default for this option is True for C++Builder, False for Delphi. This explains why the equivalent code worked in Delphi, but didn't work in C++Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run without problems the following linked example, which includes the modifications we commented before.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6grmajvoy9ijxfh/SO_test1.7z?dl=0

Comment: I don't have RAD Studio XE5, so that project was giving several missing library errors when I tried to compile it. But I copied the code of the Button OnClick event handler and pasted it into my own sample project code. It still gave the access violation error.

Comment: @MrSnrub I'm inclined to think this is a bug with FR 5, but I don't have it right now to test. Have you tried contacting FR support about this? The code, as I said, works fine with XE5 and FR 4, I think it should work fine with FR 5 - unless they changed somewhat the support for runtime constructed reports, but this particular kind of code shouldn't make FR give an AV.

By the way, before changing the dataset name and the band name I got some errors, but they stated clearly what was the problem: couldn't find dataset X, and unknown band Y.